# NSFastEnumeration in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert an Objective-C project to swift, but I am unable to find how to use NSFastEnumeration for an object of a class that conforms to NSFastEnumeration.

Here is the code in ObjC:

```
//  get the decode results
id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
for(symbol in results)
    // just grab the first barcode
    break;
```

so far I tried to find how to do this, but this doe not seems work, here is the swift code:

```
var results: ZBarSymbolSet = infoDictionary?.objectForKey(ZBarReaderControllerResults) as ZBarSymbolSet

    var symbol : ZBarSymbol? = nil;

    for symbol in results
    {    //just grab first barcode
        break;
    }
```

the error comes in for condition - "ZBarSymbolSet" does not have a member named "Generator"

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the screen shot
[image]

Comment: I'd like to hear a real solution for this as well (the only answer as of now just states why it's not working.) `NSFastEnumeration` is a heavily-used protocol all over `NSFoundation` (`NSSet`, `NSHashTable`, `NSMapTable`, `NSPointerArray`, etc) and it feels redundant to extend all of those classes just to conform to `SequenceType`, when the same `for-in` construct was already supported for those classes in Objective-C.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a while poking around the swift framework files, I finally found this nice class called `NSFastGenerator`. `NSSet` and friends seem to be using the same `Generator`.

For `ZBarSymbolSet`, here's how you'd extend it to support `for-in` loops:

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}
```

**Update:** Looks like Swift 2.0's protocol extensions fixed this for us!

Comment: That's brilliant, but Apple should do this by default for all their own NSFastEnumeration-conforming classes. As it is, I'm having to repeat this extension for every NSFastEnumeration class where I want to say `for...in`, which is nuts.

Comment: Although Swift 2.0 supports protocol extensions, they cannot have an inheritance clause, and so the technique still appears to be limited to classes.

Comment: @lukhnos the NSFastEnumeration protocol is meant for old objective-c collections. You shouldn't be using it for structs; just use SequenceType.

Answer (score 3):

Your defined class `ZBarSymbolSet` needs to implement the Swift `SequenceType` interface in order to be usable in `for <identifier> in <sequence>` syntax.  The `SequenceType` interface is

```
protocol SequenceType : _Sequence_Type {
    typealias Generator : GeneratorType
    func generate() -> Generator
}
```

and thus you see the mention of `Generator` as reported in your error message.

Also in the syntax:

```
for <identifier> in <sequence> {
  <statements>
}
```

the `<identifer>` is only in scope for `<statements>`.  Thus your second use of `symbol` in the `if` will be out of scope and an error.  One proper idiom would be:

```
var symbolFound : ZBarSymbol?

for symbol in result {
  symbolFound = symbol
  break
}

if symbolFound ...
```

If course, but the time `ZBarSymbolSet` implements `SequenceType` it would also implement `CollectionType` with `subscript` and thus the whole 'find the first element' code would be `var symbol = result[0]`

Comment: I cannot edit ZBarSymbolSet as I am using ZBar SDK http://zbar.sourceforge.net, a static library. Any alternate ???

Comment: subclass it or extend it

Answer (score 3):

Here is John Estropia's answer for Swift 3:

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet: Sequence {

    public typealias Iterator = NSFastEnumerationIterator

    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }

}
```

Then you for-in loop would look like this:

```
for element in results {
    let symbol = element as! ZBarSymbol
    // ...
}
```

This answer could be improved by also adopting the `IteratorProtocol` so you can specify the element associated type as `ZBarSymbol`. I have not figured out how to do this yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
Step1: 
extension ZBarSymbolSet: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}

Step2:
var results: NSFastEnumeration = info.objectForKey(ZBarReaderControllerResults) as NSFastEnumeration

    var symbolFound : ZBarSymbol?

    for symbol in results as ZBarSymbolSet {
        symbolFound = symbol as? ZBarSymbol
        break
    }
    resultString = NSString(string: symbolFound!.data)
```

Comment: Thanks Alok, but John's answer solved the issue that I was facing. I think your answer will help others figure out the complete picture.

Comment: In Swift 2, I'm getting the error **Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' to 'ZBarSymbolSet'** at this line `for symbol in results as ZBarSymbolSet`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it without writing an extension

```
    var iterator = NSFastEnumerationIterator(collection)
    while let element = iterator.next() {
        // use element
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you know that all objects in your `ZBarSymbolSet` are `ZBarSymbol` objects (since ObjC doesn't enforce all objects being `ZBarSymbol` objects), you can do the following:

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet {

    public struct ZBarSymbolSetIterator {
        public typealias Element = ZBarSymbol
        private let enumerator: NSFastEnumerationIterator

        init(_ symbols: ZBarSymbolSet) {
            self.enumerator = NSFastEnumerationIterator(symbols)
        }

        public mutating func next() -> ZBarSymbol {
            if let object = self.enumerator.next() {
                return object as? ZBarSymbol
            }
            else { return nil }
        }
    }

    public func makeIterator() -> ZBarSymbolSetIterator {
        return ZBarSymbolSetIterator(self)
    }
}
```

Now your for-loop will look like this:

```
for element in results {
    // element is a ZBarSymbol
}
```