# ABMultiValue address book multi-value properties compile error in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, abaddressbook

Code works in Objective-C, trying to convert to Swift.  I've provided the working Objective-C code and the Swift code that gives a compile error on line 10 (the `for subValue in aPropertyValue ...` fast enumerator.  Swift error "Type 'ABMultiValue' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'".

Some `ABPerson` properties may contain multiple values (for example multiple phone numbers) and are objects of the `ABMultiValue` class (although Xcode debugger reports them as `ABMultiValueCoreDataWrapper` class). The attached Objective-C code loops through the multiple values.  I am trying to do the same in Swift but can not get past the compile error.  Both are Xcode Command Line projects.

The Objective-C code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        ABAddressBook *addressBook = [ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook];
        NSArray *people = [addressBook people];
        for (ABPerson *person in people) {
            for (NSString *aProperty in [ABPerson properties]) {
                id aPropertyValue = [person valueForProperty: aProperty];
                if ([aPropertyValue isKindOfClass: [ABMultiValue class]]) {
                    for (id subValue in aPropertyValue) {
                        NSLog(@"%@",subValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The swift code:

```
import Foundation
import AddressBook
let addressBook = ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook()
let people = addressBook.people()
for person in people {
    for property in ABPerson.properties() {
        if let aPropertyValue : AnyObject = person.valueForProperty(property as NSString) {
            if aPropertyValue is ABMultiValue {
//                for subValue in aPropertyValue {
                for subValue in aPropertyValue as ABMultiValue {
                    println("\(subValue)") 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could obviously use the index:

```
let addressBook = ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook()
let people = addressBook.people()
for person in people {
    for property in ABPerson.properties() {
        if let multiValue = person.valueForProperty(property as NSString) as? ABMultiValue {
            for i in 0 ..< multiValue.count() {
                println(multiValue.valueAtIndex(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25872991/1271826), you can define an extension that conforms to `SequenceType`:

```
extension ABMultiValue: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
let addressBook = ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook()
let people = addressBook.people()
for person in people {
    for property in ABPerson.properties() {
        if let multiValue = person.valueForProperty(property as NSString) as? ABMultiValue {
            for identifier in multiValue {
                let value: AnyObject = multiValue.valueForIdentifier(identifier as String)
                println("\(identifier) : \(value)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```