# Scan qrcode and barcode from camera and image which picked from image library in swift

Tags: ios, swift, zbar-sdk

I'm a newbie with Ios. i'm learning swift and overlooked object c.

Currently, i'm writing an demo with swift and xcode 6.1 which can scan qrcode and barcode from camera or an image from image library.

I know that AVFoundation framework support scanning qrcode and barcode, but it can only scan from camera.

I searched and found zbarSDK which support scan code from camera and image. I do as instructions in http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ and [NSFastEnumeration in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788290/nsfastenumeration-in-swift) (convert code to swift). However, when i run app, after choosing image from library, it happen error.

This's my code

```
import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    extension ZBarSymbolSet: SequenceType {
        public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
            return NSFastGenerator(self)
        }
    }

    class FirstViewController: UIViewController, ZBarReaderDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        let reader = ZBarReaderController()

        @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            reader.delegate = self
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @IBAction func scanCode(sender: AnyObject) {
            let scanner = reader.scanner
            scanner.setSymbology(ZBAR_I25, config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, to: 0)
            reader.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
            presentViewController(reader, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
            var results: NSFastEnumeration = info["ZBarReaderControllerResults"] as NSFastEnumeration

            var symbolFound : ZBarSymbol?

            // =============== Error here ==================
            for symbol in results as ZBarSymbolSet {
                symbolFound = symbol as? ZBarSymbol
                break
            }
            var resultString = NSString(string: symbolFound!.data)
            println(resultString)

        }

    }
```

here is error image
[image]

I will very grateful if someone let me know why it happen error and how to fix it or there's any way to scan code with an image using AVFoundation or there a other library (with detail document and sample) to do this (please give detail instructions because i have just learned swift and ios for 3 weeks).
Thanks.

Comment: What error happens ? Be specific. If possible show the error message or the stack trace.

Answer (score 15):

I was also looking to read a QR code from an image and without Zbar.

You can use `CIDetector` instead. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973865/swift-no-matter-what-i-do-cidetector-is-always-nil).
In my case, I pick up a photo from the library (supposed to be a QR code, here `qrcodeImg`) and then convert it in `CIImage` to be decoded by `CIDetector`.

```
qrCodeImageView.image=qrcodeImg

let detector:CIDetector=CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
let ciImage:CIImage=CIImage(image:qrcodeImg)
var qrCodeLink=""

let features=detector.featuresInImage(ciImage)
for feature in features as! [CIQRCodeFeature] {
   qrCodeLink += feature.messageString
}

if qrCodeLink=="" {
    print("nothing")
}else{
    print("message: \(qrCodeLink)")
}
```

Comment: Hi Marie Dm, thank for your answer.
However i found other library. I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402422/zxingobjc-converting-object-c-to-swift

Comment: Hi @SonTran, I already saw this library but it seems you need to import a SDK and I didn't want that. That is why I chose this solution. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @UmeshSharma I think so but I only tried with qr codes.

Comment: @UmeshSharma it is the same CIDectetor type to use (see detector type down: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Detector_Types): "CIDetectorTypeQRCode: A detector that searches for Quick Response codes (a type of 2D barcode) in a still image or video, returning CIQRCodeFeature objects that provide information about detected barcodes."

Comment: @UmeshSharma Did you actually try to detect a barcode with this code?

Comment: Works only for 2-d barcodes. I want to work on 1-d barcodes

Comment: @MarieDm is that works for live camera stream as well? Or only for images?

Comment: @Saad No, I use AVCaptureSession & AVCaptureMetadataOutput to detect AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode

Comment: Shouldn't this be included in the library itself.

Comment: Anyhow, I was just doing some R&D. If I have to develop to this app, Possibly  I will make a component having all features in it (IF not there already) Thanks for your reply btw

Answer (score 0):

For `Swift3` following code should work for you to get result from `ZBarSDK`

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    // ADD: get the decode results
    let results: NSFastEnumeration = info[ZBarReaderControllerResults] as! NSFastEnumeration

    var symbolFound : ZBarSymbol?

    for symbol in results as! ZBarSymbolSet {
        symbolFound = symbol as? ZBarSymbol
        break
    }
    let resultString = symbolFound!.data
    print(resultString)
}
```