# How to use ZXingObjC UPC/EAN Extension support in Swift (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, zxing, barcode-scanner

I've been working on a barcode scanner (iOS/Swift) that should read either a upca+5 or upca+2. I tried the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402422/zxingobjc-converting-object-c-to-swift) and was able to read just first 12 characters. I really don't know how to go about using [ZXUPCEANExtensionSupport](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/blob/675b0872933e52f3182eb3ddef9b00ed1b25976d/ZXingObjC/oned/ZXUPCEANExtensionSupport.m)