# Swift : No Matter what I do CIDetector is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

i don't understand why this code doesn't work, the detector is always nil with the CIDetectorTypeQRCode constant, everything work with CIDetectorTypeFace.
I Supect a bug from API of Apple. This a the official doc : [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Detector_Types)

```
@IBAction func analyseTag(sender: AnyObject) {

        var detector:CIDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context:nil, options:[CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
        var decode = ""
        var ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(image: ImgChoosed.image)
        var message:String = "";

        let features = detector.featuresInImage(ciImage)
        for feature in features as [CIQRCodeFeature] {
            message += feature.messageString
        }

        if(message == "") {
            println("nothing")

        } else {
            println("\(message)")
        }



    }
```

Have you a solution?
Thank in advance guy's

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided can't have a nil `detector` because it's not an optional and the compiler would complain about several places in your code if it was.

If features is empty then you know it didn't find a QR code in your image.  Try providing a better image or turning down the `CIDetectorAccuracy`.

If features isn't empty then your cast is failing.

Edit:
You can't pass a `nil` context in the constructor.

Comment: I know for the nil detector can't be nil, but this is what it is when I declare it like this. XCode tell me : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at the line of the detectorField. I tried to put CIDetectorAccuracy to low, but this is the same. and when I switch the "ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode" for CIDectectorTypeFace, everything compile.

Comment: @Tumeconnais That error is because you can't pass a `nil` context.

Comment: So I Put context:CIContext(options: nil) and same. I don't understand :(

Comment: @Tumeconnais if a parameter in `UIKit` is force unwrapped (ends with !) then you can't pass nil.  The same goes for options in this case.

Comment: context:CIContext(options:[kCIContextPriorityRequestLow: true]) nothing with that neither, if I follow this tutorial [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift) I can put nil in context. But the things I don't understand is : if I put CIDetector(ofType: **CIDetectorTypeFace**, context:nil, options:[CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]) everythings works fine, and no error occurs.

Comment: follow/open the method with cmd + Click and you will see:     init!(ofType type: String!, context: CIContext!, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> CIDetector,
so you can't/shouldn't pass nil

Comment: in the tutorial he first creates var context : CIContext! and in the viewdidload he init, context = CIContext(options:nil)

Comment: I made everythings, and don't work, everythings work when I put CIDetectorTypeFace or CIDetectorTypeRectangle but not with CIDetectorTypeQRCode. I Think a lot that just a Bug about API because Swift is always in Beta.

Comment: I haven't solved, so I removed this functionnality from my app, now the user need to take a photo of the QRCode.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to us as well. iPhone 4s doesn't return a CIDetector of type QRCode. The other types (rectangle, face) work though…

The same code works as expected on the iPhone 6. Haven't tested on a 5 or 5s yet.

But two weeks ago it was still working on the 4s, I believe. It was still on iOS 8 back then, I guess.

Comment: Tested in a iPhone 5 and didn't work. But worked on a iPad Air 2 though. Both running iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your ImgChoosed.image is not nil.
2. Change another input image for testing.
3. Try `for feature in features as! [CIQRCodeFeature]`.

Answer (score -2):

I found that using on a device resolved this issue. The simulator seemed to always return nil for me.