# "Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error" with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, xcode8

While choosing an image from the image picker in iOS 10 Swift 3 I am getting an error - `Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error`

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    imagePost.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The image is not getting selected and updated. I need help or suggestion to know if the syntax or anything regarding this method has been changed in iOS10 or Swift 3 or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Change it from AnyObject to Any `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]`

Comment: You should just let Xcode autocomplete it for you. The method you are using I think is deprecated

Comment: Btw Xcode 8 beta 6 is the latest Swift 3 release

Comment: Thanks Leo indeed a helpful comment.

Comment: same problem here, and String: Any doesn't seem to help

Comment: Still not working . Im using Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Comment: I noticed if I use the camera instead of the library as a picker, I don't get this error, but my old code that actually uses the image still doesn't work.

Comment: Not working for me either. The data that is returned is a valid UIImage because I am able to save it to my server and it displays correctly there. It just wont load into the UIImageView

Comment: Hello,

Can you please share your code over git hub or somewhere similar, I will look into it and try to help.

Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old question but I had the same issue and have a complete implementation partly mentioned here. I found out that the keys for "editedImage" and "originalImage" are not set but "UIImagePickerControllerMediaType" and "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" are set. The URL is a link to: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=[UUID]&ext=JPG. That means the image must be loaded from the asset-Library. Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496910/unable-to-load-image-from-asset-url

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Below mentioned code did solve the problem for me -

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imagePost.image = image
    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me. I updated the function and still get the error message immediately when this function is called. And using the UIImage does not work after that.

Comment: @Tim I still get the error, but accessing the image works fine.

Comment: @jeetendra This does solve my problem, but it still giving me a warning "Instance method (didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo) nearly matches its optional requirement." When i add private or nonobj befor the func, then warning is gone but the method doesn't gets called.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me on XCode 8 and Swift 3. I'm using an iOS10 device.

Comment: Although this does helped me solve the issue of image not appearing, the error still appears in the console. Thanks though.

Comment: I agree with @KrugerBrent, this solves the issue of image not appearing, but the error remains in the console.

Comment: @Jeet could you have a look at my question. I still get that error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189732

Comment: @bibscy Sure I will have a look at it. allow me some time though.

Comment: @Jeet thank you. Now, it started to malfunction totally, meaning that this delegate method is not being called at all `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

Answer (score 11):

Remember to add delegate to self

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self // delegate added
```

Comment: Ha, you saved me.  Xcode 7 would compile and function properly without the delegate assignment... crazy.

Answer (score 10):

Below code did solve the problem:

If user perform changes to selected image pull only that image otherwise pull original image source without any changes and finally dismiss image picker view controller.

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
    }
    else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 7):

If you allow editing of the picture `imageController.allowsEditing = true` then you will need to get the edited image first:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        imagePost.image = image
    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imagePost.image = image
    } else {
        imagePost.image = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your response, but I still get the error. Could you please read my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189732

Answer (score 5):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39013450/3150830) by [Jeetendra Choudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5368667/jeetendra-choudhary) works.Although in Xcode 8 with Swift 3 , I noticed that it generates a warning :
`Instance method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' of protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'`

[image]

and suggests to add either **@nonobjc** or **private** keyword to silence the warning.If you silence the warning using these suggestions , the solution no longer works though.

Comment: Thanks for clarification make sense.

Comment: The issue is the "AnyObject" - the correct Swift 3 signature uses "Any". Don't use the Xcode suggested solutions for silencing the warning.

Answer (score 5):

I found the default images in the photo library could couse this problem.
If you drag an image from your computor  onto the simulator and choose it.
this problem is solved

Answer (score 3):

According Abdurohman's answer, i change my code and solve the problem,thanks.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: That's the only code which worked for me in Swift 3.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to viewDidload()

```
imagepicker.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "_" in function parameters.

from

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController ...
```

to

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question

Answer (score 1):

If this helps anyone, I had this happen when I subclassed UIImageView to create a rounded view.  It also happened when I added the below line in viewDidLoad()

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
```

I ended up adding the line in viewWillLayoutSubViews and it worked.  See this for more details:

[clipsToBounds causes UIImage to not display in iOS10 & XCode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136637/clipstobounds-causes-uiimage-to-not-display-in-ios10-xcode-8)

Answer (score 1):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

         let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.imageTook.image = image
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question.

Comment: This solved my problem. But can you explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Change `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]` ,
 to `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]`

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 8.1 with swift 3, After changing the delegate method as below

change your

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    imagePost.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

function to

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])

    {


imagePost.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
 picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I forgot to add UINavigationControllerDelegate along with UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

You would have added an variable at the beginning like

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

and setting delegate and call a function in viewdidload() as

```
 imagePicker.delegate = self
 viwImagePick()
```

Then explain that function as

```
  //ImagePicker
    func viwImagePick(){


        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose your source", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            print("Camera selected")
            self.openCamera()

            //Code for Camera
            //cameraf
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            print("Photo selected")
            self.openGallary()

            //Code for Photo library
            //photolibaryss
        })


        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }



    func openCamera()
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
        {
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let popover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: imagePicker)

            popover.present(from: profileImgViw.frame, in: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.any, animated: true)

        }
    }

    func openGallary()
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
        {
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
           let popover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: imagePicker)

            popover.present(from: profileImgViw.frame, in: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.any, animated: true)


        }
    }
```

Now the image is added to image view from the library

Comment: Please edit the answer to explain how is this related to actual question. It is not quite clear from your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a connection between photoImageView and the image.

Take a look my screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why 2 answer with the same content?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a connection between photoImageView and the image.

Take a look my screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imgViewPhoto.image = image
    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to also include the`UINavigationControllerDelegate` delegate. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print("image selected");
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImag
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   UIImg.image = selectedImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. 
Just copy and paste it exactly.

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
     photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question

Answer (score 0):

What I did was that once I got the image from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, I called:

```
func prepareImageForSaving(image:UIImage) {
    // create NSData from UIImage
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) else {
        // handle failed conversion
        print("jpg error")
        return
    }

    self.saveImage(imageData: imageData as NSData)
}

func saveImage(imageData: NSData) {
    imageDatas = imageData
}
```

to save it in NSData format.

The console still warned me on "[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error" but at least my imageView gets updated to the selected image rather than showing the previous one from viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

// image picker with collection view
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var collview: UICollectionView!

var image = NSMutableArray()


let imgpkr = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imgpkr.delegate = self
}




@IBAction func btnselect(_ sender: UIButton) {


    imgpkr.allowsEditing = true // false
    imgpkr.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imgpkr.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    present(imgpkr, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let choose = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as!UIImage
    let edit = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]as!UIImage

    img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    img.image = edit

    //MARK:- Add image in collview

    image.add(edit)
    collview.reloadData()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK:- Collection View


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return image.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! CollectionViewCell1

    cell.img1.image = image.object(at: indexPath.item)as! UIImage

    return cell



}
```

Answer (score -1):

For me I was getting the error:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil..."

when you select imagein imagepicker.

To get around the problem, I created the outlet for the `imageView` again.