# UICollectionView not showing images in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, ios10

My `UICollectionView` works fine in all version **except** in **iOS 10**. I am using `UIImageView` to show images.

I have images saved in the`ContentFolder` of the application.

I am using `NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];` to get the data of the image and `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];` to create the image I want to show.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set collection view's `isPrefetchingEnabled` property to false (by default it's true in iOS 10).

Comment: Thank you it works! Where did you find out about that property?

Comment: i was just read about uicollectionview updates in ios10 on apple developer site.

Answer (score 3):

clipsToBounds and cornerRadius could be having an effect. This fixed my issue. [iOS 10 GM with xcode 8 GM causes views to disappear due to roundedCorners & clipsToBounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380128/ios-10-gm-with-xcode-8-gm-causes-views-to-disappear-due-to-roundedcorners-clip/39380129#39380129)