# UIImageView images is not loading on iOS10 and Xcode 8?

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, alamofire, ios10, xcode8

UIImageView images are not loading either with downloading with Alamofire or using URL to convert to a data object and convert data object to a UIImage. My images on UITableViewCells are working but not the UIImageviews standalone in a UIView. It is giving me a blank.

UIImageViews: They are a subview of a UIView which is a subview of a UITableView

Here it is the code that Im using:

```
let imageURL = URL(string: _imageUrl)
let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)
imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

Here is the extension that I'm using with Alamofire:

```
extension UIImageView {
 func donwloadImageFrom(_ imageURL: String, contentMode: UIViewContentMode) {
    let stringUrl = URL(string: imageURL)!
    Alamofire.request(stringUrl, method: .get).response(completionHandler: { response in
        if let imageData = response.data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.contentMode = contentMode
                self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            })
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issues. First I thought it had something todo with the image loading library I was using but. Straight up loading an url doesnt seem to work either

Comment: I found the answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380128/ios-10-gm-with-xcode-8-gm-causes-views-to-disappear-due-to-roundedcorners-clip/39380129#39380129)

Answer (score 0):

I think the awakeFromNib() function bit changed.
I don't know exact reason but, after adding

```
layoutIfNeeded()
```

into awakeFromNib().
Made it works.