# ImageView dosen't appear after using clipsToBounds for making it round

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

The ImageView dosen't appear after using clipsToBounds for making it round, but if i remove these lines it shows on the storyboard.

Here is a snip for the code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {[super viewDidLoad];


self.ProfilePhotoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.ProfilePhotoImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
self.ProfilePhotoImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

self.ProfilePhotoImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
self.ProfilePhotoImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view. 
}
```

Comment: Image don't appear after using above code for making it round. But if i remove these lines it shows on the storyboard :(

Comment: Place the above code in`viewWillAppear` and check.

Comment: Thanks brother. It worked like charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the imaged load on viewDidLoad() simple add

```
 [self layoutIfNeeded];
```

previous the cornerRadious setup.

Ref: [iOS 10 GM with xcode 8 GM causes views to disappear due to roundedCorners & clipsToBounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380128/ios-10-gm-with-xcode-8-gm-causes-views-to-disappear-due-to-roundedcorners-clip/39380129#39380129)

Answer (score 1):

Place the above code in `viewWillAppear` method and check.

Like,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.ProfilePhotoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.ProfilePhotoImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.ProfilePhotoImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    self.ProfilePhotoImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    self.ProfilePhotoImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

}
```

Comment: I have placed the above code in -(void)viewWillAppear. I have the above image as profile pic in a view of page view controller now the problem is until i turn over that page again the image is not loading in that view but once i scroll through the page view controller and come back the image gets to display.