# Animation bug in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints, ios10

Since iOS 10 I have noticed animating a layout change ( `layoutIfNeeded()` ) isn't animating. Here is my UIView extension that works great on iOS 9 and below.

```
func slideIn(from edgeConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, withDuration duration: Double = 0.25, finishedAnimating: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        edgeConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: .BeginFromCurrentState,
            animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded() },
            completion: { didComplete in
                finishedAnimating?()
        })
    }
}

func slideOut(from edgeConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, withDuration duration: Double = 0.25, finishedAnimating: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        edgeConstraint.constant = -self.frame.height
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: .BeginFromCurrentState,
            animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded() },
            completion: { didComplete in
                finishedAnimating?()
        })
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why it isn't animating?

Comment: Are you also having problems on a real device?

Comment: @DanLevy Yes iPhone 6S iOS 10.0.1

Comment: What do you mean by "not working right"?

Comment: @Aaron it isn't animating. Instead of sliding from one point to another, it is jumping to the final point without any animation.

Comment: Are you using Swift 3?

Comment: @Aaron I am using Swift 2.3

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, that didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your animation blocks you're calling `self.layoutIfNeeded()` where `self` is the instance of `UIView` that you want to animate. Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` redraws the view that the method is called upon and all if it's subviews. In your case, you don't want to redraw the `UIView`, you want to redraw the view's superview.

Your functions would make sense and work properly if they were called in a view controller but since they are called in an extension on the `UIView` itself, you need to call something like `view.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: So that worked. But why did it work on iOS 9 without referring to the superview, and now on iOS 10 I have to specify the superview?

Comment: The bug should be OS agnostic so I'm not sure exactly why it would be working on iOS 9.

Comment: It is not actually OS agnostic. This used to really work on 9 and older versions. This new behaviour which turns out to be a fixed on a bug before was introduced on iOS10 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39548367/1045672 - See Apple release note.