# UIimageView disappear on device but can see on view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, xib

I have a `UIImageView` on tableview Cell, it worked fine before
 but now it disappear on device

I update to **Xcode 8**  **ios 10**
I trun on Xib, it show up, I choosed
then the `UIImageView` never show again
[image]

screenShot
[image]

It weird, I can see the `UIImageView` on View Hierarchy but it  disappear on device

**Edit for answer**
I found this question
[clipsToBounds causes UIImage to not display in iOS10 & XCode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136637/clipstobounds-causes-uiimage-to-not-display-in-ios10-xcode-8)

VictorJi's answer is worked
move `layer.masksToBounds` and `layer.cornerRadius` from `awakeFromNib` to `drawRect:(CGRect)rect` then the `UIImageView` show again

But I don't understand why just affect `UIImageView`, `UILabel` is ok

Comment: Please post a screenshot

Comment: OK, I add the screenshot

Comment: You should add layoutIfNeeded() before layer modifications. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39815405/3718570