# image disappears when styling class to make a round image

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

```
class RoundImage: UIImageView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }

     ...

    func setupView() {
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor
        self.clipsToBounds = clip
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
    }


    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }

}
```

I am using the following class to style my UIImageViews. I want to make them circular. When I add the following line of code `self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2` to make this possible, my entire image disappears.
When I use a hardcoded value like 50 (since the width of my image is 100) it works. But when I want to make it dynamic this way, it seems to fail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with this problem a few days ago.
You should add `layoutIfNeeded()` before layer modifications.

In your case:

```
func setupView() {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor
        self.clipsToBounds = clip
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
 }
```

Comment: perfect, this finally made it work. Since xCode 8, Apple seems to be more strict about these type of things..

Answer (score 1):

When this code gets run the view hasn't been sized yet, so the width is incorrect.  Try putting a listener on frame:

```
override var frame : CGRect {
    didSet {
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added it to the code, but my imageview is still blank