# Images are not loading properly

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcode8, sdwebimage, swift2

I have very simple iOS app - it have TableView and list of custom cells in this TableView. There is an ImageView (that use ***downloadedFrom*** method to load images) in each cell.

After updating my Xcode to 8 version and converting project to Swift 2.3 I got very interesting result when - I reload list of items inside TableView - first cells on screen don't have any images and when i start to scroll down i see that other images are loaded fine. When scroll back to top - all images are fine.

I also tried to change the way of image loading to library called SDWebImage but result is the same. What is wrong?

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloadedFrom(link link:String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode) {
    guard
        let url = NSURL(string: link)
        else {return}
    contentMode = mode
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.MIMEType where mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data where error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.image = image
        }
    }).resume()
}}
```

Comment: SDWebImage working perfectly if you need then i upload my code that i use

Comment: I am sure that it works well but it shows the same behaviour: first cells don't have any images until i start to scroll

Comment: Then use placeholder for this . its show you your place holder image until your image not download and not loaded into image view

Comment: They are not loaded at all. Doesn't matter how much time i will spend looking on placeholders - images are not loading until i start to scroll table

Comment: in my project i don't have face this kind of problem

Comment: i also didn't see any problems before updating to xcode 8 / swift 2.3

Comment: ohh then say that you are working in xcode 8.0 and swift version 2.3

Comment: had you read my question?

Comment: Ya i read it but in my mind i thinking it about Xcode 7.3 and swift  2.0 . so sorry about it i don't have Xcode 8.0 in my mac right now . if i solve your issue in my friends pc then i give you update .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the loading method but in rounded corners of images.
The problem with rounded corners in Xcode 8 and iOS 10 can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136637/clipstobounds-causes-uiimage-to-not-display-in-ios10-xcode-8).