# Picking image from photo library

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm following this [Apple Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1) and I'm getting this error:

> Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

while selecting image from Photo Library.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xCode 8 - Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009889/xcode-8-creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error)

Answer (score 0):

try this... I did it it ones like this.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    var standardImg: UIImage!
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            standardImg = image
            photoImageView.image = standardImg
        }
            imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func addImage(_ sender: UIButton) {

        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
//        sender.setImage(standardImg, for: UIControlState())

    }
}
```

Comment: I changed `selectedImage` to `image` and I got same error.

Comment: did you also change the function? if you see to my function parameters they are different then yours..

Comment: Also create a var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! and say imagePicker.dismiss

Comment: Yes, I also change function parameters :) I added `var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! ` and `imagePicker.dismiss`instead of `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` still same error. After picking image it returns to application and I still have default photo

Comment: i edited my answer again.. this is how i've done it.. 
EDIT: don't forget to put in the delegate ("UIImagePickerControllerDelegate") after your class types

Comment: Same error, I don't know what could be wrong. Maybe this photos in simulator are wrong.

Comment: edited again.. i tested it and got the same error, try to work with a breakpoint in the imagePickerController delegate function, to see if it goes in the function, retype or do not set the function private,... this worked for me! do not forget the privacy setting in info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Solution is

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{

    if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
      photoImageView.image = selectedImage
    } 
    else{
       print("Picking image is not in correct format")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```