# Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error Objective-C Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode8, ios10

While choosing an image from the image picker in `iOS 10` `Objective-C` and `Xcode 8`. I am getting an error -

> **Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error**

.

It was ok for the previous version.

Here is my code:

```
UIImagePickerController* imgPicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imgPicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and the delegate method to recive the image is..

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
       [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
       UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

I also tried other delegate function..

```
 -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
}
```

but error not going.

I am not sure is it the bug of Xcode 8?
 If any one faced the issue and solved please help to fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009889/xcode-8-creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error ?

Comment: its a swift version. also i worked with new delegate method.but not working.

Comment: how you have solved this ??

Comment: i couldnt solve it yet..

Answer (score 34):

It's a bug. It's just a false warning. No bad thing is happening to the working of the app, so ignore the warning.

Comment: there is a problem, when I'm picking the IMAGE and then let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1) to send it via POST HTML I'm receiving this error and the image is not uploaded

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov But that has nothing to do with the warning. If you have a question about whatever it is you're trying to do, ask it as a _question_ so you can show your code and we can help.

Comment: Hi @Chisx I've never seen this warning actually halt the program, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

i go through apple document and use this

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

in **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** method.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {  

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];  
imageViewPreview.image = chosenImage;  

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];     

}
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
  UIImage *tempImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempImage.size);
  [tempImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, tempImage.size.width, tempImage.size.height)];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() CGImage]];

  [self.myimageview setImage:image];
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

Update the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method to the new method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
```

FROM THE PREVIOUS METHOD:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

This fixed the issue for me.
IDE Version: Xcode8.2.1

Comment: The warning is generated _before_ the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method is called. Therefore the exact signature of the method has nothing to do with the matter.

Answer (score -2):

Add this.

```
imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Comment: plist add privacy-photo Library usage description.

Answer (score -4):

I solved this problem by adding following initialisation of `BitmapInfo` parameter which used in `CGContextRef context` variable:

```
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
```

instead of 
`CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);`

P.S:

So now my `CGContextRef context` looks as following

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
        imageSize.width,
        imageSize.height,
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
        0,
        colorSpace,
        bitmapInfo);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Comment: Can you please explain it how it work with my question?