# Xcode 8 - swift 3: Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Tags: swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, xcode8

I get an error when selecting an image with UIImagePicker:

```
[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
```

I'm using Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.
I've already searched all around the web but nothing seems to solve my problem, please help!

Here it's my code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var isSelected: Bool = false
var imgPicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //imgPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imgPicker.delegate = self
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = false
    imgPicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imgPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPostPicture", sender: image)
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func askImagePickerSource(sender: UIViewController) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.imgPicker.sourceType = .camera
            self.imgPicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .camera)!
            sender.present(self.imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.imgPicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
            sender.present(self.imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (UIAlertAction) in
            sender.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        alert.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        sender.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.imgPicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        sender.present(self.imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toPostPicture" {
        if let postPictureVC = segue.destination as? PostPictureVC {
            if let image = sender as? UIImage {
                postPictureVC.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xCode 8 - Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009889/xcode-8-creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue by not adding delegate as '**self**' for the UIImagePickerController. After adding it I was able to get the selected image from gallery. But even after adding delegate as **self** and able to access the image (Display on an ImageView), I was still getting the same error. After a further research on SO I got to know that this is just a bug and doesn't affect the app in any way.

See also ["Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error Objective-C Xcode 8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086636/creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error-objective-c-xcode-8)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the `.debugDescription` of the `info` parameter in your picker delegate?

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
print(info.debugDescription)
...
}
```

Comment: Here follows the info.debugDescription:["UIImagePickerControllerMediaType": public.image, "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL": assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED&ext=JPG, "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage": <UIImage: 0x608000287800> size {3000, 2002} orientation 0 scale 1.000000]

Comment: if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            
            // Save your image
            
        }
        else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            
            //Save your image
           
        } else{
            print("Something went wrong")
        }