# Image picker does not pick image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

EDIT: I have looked at other answers, but they do not fix my issue. My issue is the info for the image should be printed to the console, but it is not printed.

My imagePicker is not working properly. Here is the code I used to set it up:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])  {
    print(info)
    picker.delegate = self
    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] {

        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage as? UIImage

    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage as? UIImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        logoImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
}
```

When the picker is presented and I select an image, the (info) is NOT printed and the compiler throws this error:

`[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error`

I have searched everywhere to find an answer, but nothing has worked. Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: Why are you using `"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"` instead of the proper constants provided by the API?

Comment: if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as! UIImage {

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code! when you got this error ? and why are you setting delegate in this method ?  and make sure that `logoImageView` is there or not nil. Because if you put break point in this method and check then you will get edited or original image in `selectedImageFromPicker` !

Comment: @rmadd can you go into more detail?

Comment: 1) picker.delegate = self

Declare this line out side the delegate function either in viewDidLoad() or before where you presenting imagePicker.

2) use like this
info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

hope it's works for you

Comment: @jaydeep look at the question.... that is in there

Comment: @chillin' Jaydeep is right. Your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo ` method will not even get fired if you place the `picker.delegate = self` there. Cut and paste it in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method. Also use proper constants than using raw string.

Comment: Instead of using your own string keys to access values out of the `info` dictionary, use the key constants defined by the API. Example: Use `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` instead of `info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]`.

Comment: (1) If you are using Swift 3, you need to change `imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])` to `imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])`. If you let Xcode auto complete, you'll see it now uses `Any` instead of `AnyObject`. (2) If that doesn't fix the error, look at @matt's answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086636/creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error-objective-c-xcode-8.