# input file occurs error:[Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error] on cordova, ios 10

Tags: cordova, input, ios10

I have found the input[type='file'] can't get image on ios 10 with cordova.

there is an error on Xcode:  Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error.

l have found the question about this with native code, but how could I use it on cordova? [xCode 8 - Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009889/xcode-8-creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error)

Comment: This is an apple issue on the webview, you can report the bug to apple https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/. But it looks like a warning more than an error, it seems to work for me on iOS 10.1, but the images are upside down