# xcode 8.1 & iOS 10.1.1 "[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error" for UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Trying to allow a user to select a photo from their photo library and then display that image in a UIImageView. Photo library is showing up just fine, but when I select a photo from my library, I get this error "[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error".

Stepped through my code below but the error comes up only when selecting an image which does not occur inside either of these 2 functions.

```
@IBAction func openPhotoLibraryButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {        
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage!
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.6)
    let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    imagePicked.image = compressedJPGImage
}
```

Tried the solutions suggested here: [xCode 8 - Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009889/xcode-8-creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error) but none of them worked, and it sounds like several folks did not get this issue resolved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding `_` before picker? I believe the method was changed and the one you are using is deprecated, you should be able to let it autocomplete.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) { 
  if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6) {
      let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
      imagePicked.image = compressedJPGImage
    }
  } else {
    print("Image Picker Failure")
    //handle any possible image picker issues/failures so that app doesn't crash in the future
    //troubleshoot further if it always hits this
  }
  dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used _ before picker: and got same error. The error occurs before first line of the method because it shows up before a print statement I added at the start of the imagePickerController(). Also it fails worse now with a new fatal error: 2016-12-06 16:45:53.105207 CameraDemo[714:226333] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
in image picker func
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2016-12-06 16:45:53.330483 CameraDemo[714:226333] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Not sure how meaningful it is to set a breakpoint on the method signature but I did and it did not stop there. It stopped on the first line of the method which seems to be the culprit line:         let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage!