# Generic - Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an image picker controller. I want to select an image from the photo library and place it in the rounded image view. The image gets placed successfully in the image view but still I get this error "[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error". 
 I have seen many other questions for this but none of them solves my problem. All the questions say that `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` wasn't called but mine is not the case. My image is shown in the image view and I still get the error.

I have set the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Picker is defined as follows:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
```

Delegate is set in `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
picker.delegate = self
```

Photo Library is opened as:

```
self.picker.allowsEditing = false
        self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My code of `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        userImageView.image = image
    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am using xcode 8 and swift 3. Please help.

Comment: Seems like it's just a message in the console and will not cause any problems.

Comment: Can i use the image for a web service call without a problem?

Comment: Sure you can. I send the `image` obtained to my server which doesn't have any problems.

Comment: Thanks alot! I have been searching for a solution since a few hours

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009889/xcode-8-creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error) is a discussion about this issue, but none of the methods mentioned removed the message for me. But I can use the image without any problems.

Comment: Yes I had gone through this before posting the question. But in my case image appears in the imageview as we select it. That's why posted a separate one.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea of the meaning of this message. I just ignore it as it doesn't cause any problems. Just wait for other for the true explanation! :)

Comment: i also have this problem, but yes it's causing problem. Image posted is showing up as a blank image when received from server.