# File upload error from UIWebview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwebview

I am trying to upload a photo from UIWebView that has a HTML form for image upload, after clicking the button it gives me two options:

1.Take Photo
2.Photo Library

but when I select photo from library it shows below message in console:

> creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Currently using Xcode 8.3.2. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: are you test on device or simulator , i think this warning only not crash

Comment: I am testing on device. yes it's not a crash but it's getting this message

Comment: could u post your code where u got this warning? I believe it will be "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo"

Comment: ok  xcode  issue  you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009889/xcode-8-creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a bug in xcode. If you select images from gallery and camera and it return images prorerly. That means your images is right and you can ignore this.  If you are not getting return images. That means your image is not right formate.