# Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error UIImagePickerController() , unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

Swift Version 3
Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

This question has been asked and answered before. Yet, I cannot find a way fix this error. 
["Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error" with UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009889/creating-an-image-format-with-an-unknown-type-is-an-error-with-uiimagepickerco)

When a new picture is selected from Photo Library, I get this error

> *Generic Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error.*

I select the photo and when I tap choose, I get error in `func takePhoto` where I do this assignment `self?.imgView.image = newImage`

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   Printing description of newImage: expression produced error: error:
>   /var/folders/s0/xq_zc7l56m1__n1qjk29p6tw0000gn/T/./lldb/2631/expr1.swift:1:80:
>   error: use of undeclared type 'UIKit'
>   Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer>(bitPattern:
>   0x118055200)!.pointee)
>                                                                                  ^~~~~

```
typealias imagePickerHelperCompletion = ((UIImage?) -> Void)!

class ImagePickerHelper: NSObject {

 weak var viewController: UIViewController!
 var cameraFlashMode: UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode   //flash, no flash
 var photoLibraryIsVisible: Bool
 var cameraDevice: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice //front, back camera
 var completion: imagePickerHelperCompletion


   init(viewController: UIViewController, cameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode, photoLibraryIsVisible: Bool,cameraDevice: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice, completion: imagePickerHelperCompletion) {

    self.viewController = viewController
    self.completion = completion
    self.cameraFlashMode = cameraFlashMode
    self.photoLibraryIsVisible = photoLibraryIsVisible
    self.cameraDevice = cameraDevice

    //super.init() implemented by subclasses to initializer a new object (the receiver) immediately after memory has been allocated
    super.init()

    self.showPhotoSourceSelection()
}


//show camera or photo library
func showPhotoSourceSelection() {

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Take new photo", message: "Would you like to open \n Camera or Photo Library?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.showImagePicker(sourceType: .camera)
    }

    let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.showImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in  }

        actionSheet.addAction(cameraAction)
    if photoLibraryIsVisible == true { actionSheet.addAction(photoLibraryAction) }
        actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)
      viewController.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func showImagePicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true //user can crop the image, or do some editing
    imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
    imagePicker.delegate = self

      if imagePicker.sourceType == .camera {
         imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = cameraFlashMode
         imagePicker.cameraDevice = self.cameraDevice
    }
    viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}//end of class



 extension ImagePickerHelper: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



//if user did take a photo
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print(info)
  //prints out ["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage": <UIImage: 0x610000294320> size {746, 498} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, "UIImagePickerControllerMediaType": public.image, "UIImagePickerControllerCropRect": NSRect: {{0, 0}, {2661, 1779}}, "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL": assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED&ext=JPG, "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage": <UIImage: 0x610000299320> size {2668, 1780} orientation 0 scale 1.000000]



    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        completion(image)
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
          viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
          completion(image)

        } else {
        print("something is wrong line \(#line)")
       }
    }


}//end of extension






class ProfileViewController: UITableViewController {

  var imagePickerHelper: ImagePickerHelper!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
 }

  @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

     //create instance of ImagePickerHelper and take photo, or get it from photoLibrary
      imagePickerHelper = ImagePickerHelper(  viewController: self, cameraFlashMode: .auto,photoLibraryIsVisible: true, cameraDevice: .front,
        completion: { [weak self] (newImage) in
     })
   }
}//end of class
```

Comment: Works perfectly on the simulator, no error. Make sure that you are not picking an image that is in iCloud and not stored in your phone. Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145).

Comment: @oyalhi I am not even signed in with the apple id. The iphone device is fully reset as new.