# How to fix libraries showing in red in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Sudently, in all my Xcode projects System libraries show in red and I don't know how to fix it.

What I've tried:

- I deleted xcode as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812614/5918849
- restarted machine
- downloaded same version Xcode 8.3.3 from https://developer.apple.com/download/
- opened .xcworkspace, General/Targets/Linked Frameworks and Libraries
- added all frameworks that were showing in red and built the project

However, they still show in red.

Why do I want to fix it?

I have tried to implement `UIImagePickerController()`.
I asked another question here:
 [Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error UIImagePickerController() , unexpectedly found nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189732)
After `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method is called, inside `func takePhoto` in the completion handler I get error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   Printing description of newImage: expression produced error: error:
>   /var/folders/s0/xq_zc7l56m1__n1qjk29p6tw0000gn/T/./lldb/2631/expr1.swift:1:80:
>   error: use of undeclared type 'UIKit'
>   Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer>(bitPattern: 0x118055200)!.pointee) ^~~~~

[image]

[image]

Comment: To your main question: I never used `Security.framework`, but there is no need to explicitly link `Foundation.framework`and `UIKit.framework` to your project, because they are provided by Xcode in any case. So I believe you can just delete the red references.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Should I  remove reference or move to trash?

Comment: Normally, if you delete something from the project navigator, it asks if you want to delete the reference only or move the referenced file also to the trash. If the reference is red, however, it cannot move the referenced file to the trash, so it should also not ask for these options and delete the reference.