# Scanning barcode from UIImage natively (i.e., not using ZBar)

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, uiimage, barcode

I've been using the native barcode scanner functionality provided by apple since iOS7 and it is great, but I needed to scan some static images I had so I could automatically catalogue some barcodes.

I couldn't find a way to do this natively, so I used an open source package called zBar, and for the most part, it works fine.

However, it returns false values often and sometimes flat out fails to find the barcode. I also built the c++ library from scratch but I got the same results in my OS X build.  It also seems to be an abandoned project.

Apple's native solution finds the barcode on this static image even if I scan the image from my computer monitor!  Same thing goes for the images that return false/incorrect values.

So is there anyway to use apple's libraries to scan a UIImage?

Comment: Have you found any solution for that or it is not possible for now?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: CIDetector for QRCodes on UIImage. Check documentation.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317071/scan-qrcode-and-barcode-from-camera-and-image-which-picked-from-image-library-in

Comment: zxing objc port seems to be quite updated now. And from my few testing it recognizing better than CoreImage do. Even if CI do encoding. See   https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option available now is MLKit from Firebase.

Add Firebase to your project after setting up your project in their console https://firebase.google.com

I use cocoapods to manage dependencies, if you do then add this to your Podfile and `pod update`:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionBarcodeModel'
```

Here's a demo view controller implementation in which you pick a barcode image from your photo library to be scanned by ML kit, and the results are printed in a label.

```
// (Don't forget to ask for Photos access by including this in your info.plist)

    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable photo library access to select a photo from your library.</string>



import Firebase

class MyDemoViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    lazy var vision = Vision.vision()
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            print("Button capture")

            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.checkForCodeInImage(image: image)
        })
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    }

    internal func checkForCodeInImage(image: UIImage) {
        let detector = vision.barcodeDetector(options: VisionBarcodeDetectorOptions(formats: .all))
        let vImage = VisionImage(image: image)

        detector.detect(in: vImage) { features, error in
            guard error == nil, let barcodes = features, barcodes.isEmpty == false else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.textLabel.text = "No code found in selected image."
                }
                return
            }

            var text = ""

            for barcode in barcodes {

                guard let rawValue = barcode.rawValue else {
                    continue
                }

                let corners = barcode.cornerPoints
                let displayValue = barcode.displayValue

                print("Corners: \(String(describing: corners))")
                print("Found: \(String(describing: displayValue))")

                text.append(rawValue)
                text.append("\n\n")

//                let valueType = barcode.valueType
//                switch valueType {
//                case .wiFi:
//                    let ssid = barcode.wifi!.ssid
//                    let password = barcode.wifi!.password
//                    let encryptionType = barcode.wifi!.type
//                case .URL:
//                    let title = barcode.url!.title
//                    let url = barcode.url!.url
//                default:
//                    // See API reference for all supported value types
//                    break
//                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textLabel.text = text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a link to their documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/read-barcodes

Comment: I'll assume this one succeeds where the others failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
if (detector)  {
  NSArray* featuresR = [detector featuresInImage:scannedImg.CIImage];
  NSString* decodeR;
  for (CIQRCodeFeature* featureR in featuresR)  {
    NSLog(@"decode %@ ",featureR.messageString);
    decodeR = featureR.messageString;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I so far have not gotten this to work.  Sometimes the UIImage doesn't have a CIImage, and you have to manually recreate it.  Even then the code is never returning a barcode for me.  Still investigating