# Retrieve ALAsset or PHAsset from file URL

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension, photokit, ios-extensions

Selecting images in Photos.app to pass to an action extension seems to yield paths to images on disk (e.g.: `file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/109APPLE/IMG_9417.JPG`). Is there a way to get the corresponding ALAsset or PHAsset?

The URL looks like it corresponds to the `PHImageFileURLKey` entry you get from calling `PHImageManager.requestImageDataForAsset`. I'd hate to have to iterate through all PHAssets to find it.

Comment: That's an NSURL. Do you not see how to get from there to a PHAsset?

Comment: I don't. There's `fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs` but that only takes the `assets-library://` URLs.

Comment: Hmm, it's even worse than that. You can't even get into the library this way because of sandboxing.

Comment: What about ALAssetsLibrary `assetForURL`?

Comment: Also requires the assets-library scheme (not that that stopped me: I tried both `assetForURL` and `fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs` for kicks; no dice).

Comment: I may be on the crazy-limb here, but it seems like there is _no way_ that all those photo extensions in iOS 8 are being handed file URLs and doing what they do. Did you ask _that_ question?

Comment: Right. A photo-editing extension does in fact give you the PHAsset (or some other PhotoKit thing). However, I want to play with multiple photos simultaneously (i.e., hit the Select button and tap a few photos) and for that you need a share or action extension. For those I can see why having the file is useful: you're probably uploading them somewhere or doing some processing on the actual data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did what I didn't want to do and threw this dumb search approach together. It works, although it's horrible, slow and gives me memory issues when the photo library is large.

As a noob to both Cocoa and Swift I'd appreciate refinement tips. Thanks!

```c
func PHAssetForFileURL(url: NSURL) -> PHAsset? {
    var imageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    imageRequestOptions.version = .Current
    imageRequestOptions.deliveryMode = .FastFormat
    imageRequestOptions.resizeMode = .Fast
    imageRequestOptions.synchronous = true

    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(nil)
    for var index = 0; index < fetchResult.count; index++ {
        if let asset = fetchResult[index] as? PHAsset {
            var found = false
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset,
                options: imageRequestOptions) { (_, _, _, info) in
                    if let urlkey = info["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? NSURL {
                        if urlkey.absoluteString! == url.absoluteString! {
                            found = true
                        }
                    }
            }
            if (found) {
                return asset
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is commentary on ("refinement tips") to your auto-answer. SO comments don't cut it for code samples, so here we go.

1. You can replace your for-index loop with a simpler for-each loop. E.g. something like:

   ```
   for asset in PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(nil)
   ```
2. As of the last time I checked, the key in `info["PHImageFileURLKey"]` is undocumented. Be apprised. I don't think it will get you rejected, but the behavior could change at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I definitely prefer the for .. in syntax, but PHFetchResult doesn't implement the Generator protocol and can't be iterated that way (unless something's changed recently).

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. And [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25872991/170871) indicates you need SequenceType (not Generator, turns out) to make even NSFastEnumeration-conformant types iterable.

Comment: Edited comment, out of order: @Soybean I can only speak to Objective-C right now, but there, it would be `NSFastEnumeration`, and yes it does: `@interface PHFetchResult : NSObject <NSCopying, NSFastEnumeration>` :)