# delete one video from asset or album

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8

How can delete one video from asset/album in iOS8

1. When I use **UIImagePickerController** for purpose of selection
2. then I **select one Video** from asset/album
3. in Info Dictionary I got response on **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** method

   ```
    {
       UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";

       UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL = "file:///Users/appaspect2/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A61DFE3B-8BA0-4A18-939A-2B0BC2F6084E/data/Containers/Data/Application/69E55783-CB4F-4620-9C81-B3948F5A843B/tmp/trim.1202C1FA-6130-4BC7-AA31-391CC7E0D7B6.MOV";

       UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=189B68BD-17D0-4665-A065-11A40B0F2B25&ext=MOV";
   }
   ```
4. I want to delete file this file which is select in **UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL** or asset/album video

Answer (score 0):

AssestsLibrary do not have any such method. But after searching about this I found in ios8 deleting photos might be possible using the Photos Framework

Check the documentation of Photos Framework

For deleting assets refer to PHAssetChangeRequest

```
+ (void)deleteAssets:(id<NSFastEnumeration>)assets
```

Comment: if I have one URL "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=189B68BD-17D0-4665-A065-11A40B0F2B25&ext=MOV" then how can pass it from this ?  
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:videoURL];
        } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? @"Success." : error));
        }];

Comment: you can fetch PHAsset from file url and then pass it to deleteAssets method. I have not checked but think this is how it will work. Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661938/retrieve-alasset-or-phasset-from-file-url

Comment: I tried PHFetchResult *asset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[info[@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]] options:nil] firstObject];
                                                     NSLog(@"asset %@",asset);

and Output I got : <PHAsset: 0x7f8a1492fa40> 79667072-F045-4B27-9B0E-75EACA6B9652/L0/001 mediaType=2/0, assetSource=0, (713x320), creationDate=2013-05-24 06:52:12 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 

But when I pass it. It will be crash.

Comment: check this link - https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS8-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/Photos.framework/PHAsset.h You have to get - (id)ALAssetURL; and pass this. Try this, hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

Finally so much effort I am enable to delete file of asset/album video for iOS8 Only.

You can add this in **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** Method

```
PHFetchResult *asset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[info[@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]] options:nil] firstObject];
NSLog(@"asset %@",asset);

[self toggleFavoriteForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset];
```

and Add One Method For Delete Asset Video

```
- (void)toggleFavoriteForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset {
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    // Create a change request from the asset to be modified.
    BOOL req = [asset canPerformEditOperation:PHAssetEditOperationDelete];
    if (req) {
        NSLog(@"true");
        [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[asset]];
    }
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Finished Delete asset. %@", (success ? @"Success." : error));
}];
}
```