# Editing Live Photos using Core Image in Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, swift-playground, phlivephoto

I'm having some trouble creating a `PHLivePhotoEditingContext` in order to apply filters using `CoreImage`.

However, in order to create a `PHLivePhotoEditingContext` the steps are to:

1. Instantiate a `PHAsset` object.
2. Call the `requestContent​Editing​Input(with:​completion​Handler:​)`
3. Use the `PHContentEditingInput` to instantiate a `PHLivePhotoEditingContext`.

However, my understanding of `PHAsset` is it's only available for apps and not Swift Playgrounds. Am I wrong in that assessment? If I'm wrong are there any ways to create a `PHLivePhotoEditingContext` to edit live photos in my swift playground (stored in the `Resources` directory as a `.mov` and `.JPG`? If I can't create a `PHLivePhotoEditingContext` are there alternate ways to efficiently apply `Core Image` filters onto live photos within my playground?

**I'm currently writing my code out in a playground but ultimately​ it will go in a playground book, so if it works in the playground book and not the playground that is fine.**

Comment: My understanding of PHAsset is the same. not sure how we can retrieve the PHAsset in the playground, I tried to load PHAsset from URL in the playground but failed (maybe you can try play with that).  And talking about Live Photo in the playground, maybe you want read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990830/working-with-live-photos-in-playground

Comment: @XueYu Yup, I'm failing to load it from the URL too. Just out of curiosity does it just say PHUnauthorizedFetchResult? That's what I'm getting.

Comment: I tried several ways got different errors, I tried with the answers here and got nil → http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661938/retrieve-alasset-or-phasset-from-file-url

Comment: One possible solution would maybe just split the video into frames myself and modify them like that. The thing is I am building a playground book so if it works and there and not the playground that is fine too..