# Swift watchOS 2 - CMSensorDataList

Tags: swift, core-motion, watchos-2

Short: I don't know how to extract the CMRecordedAccelerometerData from the CMSensorDataList after getting one from the CMSensorRecorder.
Apple isn't providing any documentation, yet.

Maybe someone has a hint for me? ;)

```
func startMovementDetection(){
    var accDataList = self.cmSensorRecorder!.accelerometerDataFrom(self.startDate, to: NSDate()) as CMSensorDataList

    CMRecordedAccelerometerData() //that's the class i want to extract from CMSensorDataList
}
```

Okay, problem solved with this one here: [NSFastEnumeration in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788290/nsfastenumeration-in-swift/25872991#25872991)

With Swift 3.0 it changes to:

```
extension CMSensorDataList: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any code snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//First make the extension tu use enumerate in the for-in loop
extension CMSensorDataList: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}

//Now you can query the recorded data
func printData(){
    let date = NSDate()
    let recorder = CMSensorRecorder()
    let sensorData: CMSensorDataList = recorder.accelerometerDataFromDate(initialDate!, toDate: date)!

    for (index, data) in sensorData.enumerate() {
        print(index, data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Swift 4 approach. First, you’ll need to make CMSensorDataList conform to Sequence by means of an extension:

```
extension CMSensorDataList: Sequence {
    public typealias Iterator = NSFastEnumerationIterator
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate over CMSensorDataList to obtain CMRecordedAccelerometerData instances, each consisting of a `timestamp` and an `acceleration`:

```
let rec = CMSensorRecorder() // and d1 and d2 are Dates
if let list = rec.accelerometerData(from: d1, to: d2) {
    for datum in list {
        if let accdatum = datum as? CMRecordedAccelerometerData {
            let accel = accdatum.acceleration
            let t = accdatum.timestamp
            // do something with data here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Marcus's answer in Swift 4:

```
//First make the extension to use enumerate in the for-in loop
extension CMSensorDataList: Sequence {
    public typealias Iterator = NSFastEnumerationIterator

    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}

//Now you can query the recorded data
func printData(){
    let date = Date()
    let recorder = CMSensorRecorder()
      let accelerometerData = recorder.accelerometerData(from: startDate, to: endDate)

     for (index, data) in (accelerometerData?.enumerated())! {
                    print(index, data)
      }
}
```

Comment: No SequenceType in Swift 4. This doesn't compile.

Comment: It's just Sequence, see amended answer