# CMSensorDataList enumeration in swift on ios11

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

There are a number of discussions about enumerating through CMSensorDataList around, however, they all have the same example:

```
extension CMSensorDataList: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work on ios11 for multiple reasons (`NSFastGenerator` doesn't exist, `SequenceType` has been renamed to `Sequence`).

How do I enumerate through a `CMSensorDataList` in modern swift?

Comment: Here is a Swift 3 version: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31101573/1187415

Answer (score 0):

if swift 4 and 5 it will work

```
extension CMSensorDataList: Sequence {
    public typealias Iterator = NSFastEnumerationIterator
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}
```

now you will need to do like blow

```
let rec = CMSensorRecorder() 
if let list = rec.accelerometerData(from: date1, to: date2) {
    for item in list {
        if let data = item as? CMRecordedAccelerometerData {
            let x = data.acceleration.x
            print("X: \(x)")
        }
    }
}
```