# NSFastEnumeration in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nsfastenumeration

I am trying to iterate over a object of `CMSensorDataList` class returned by `CMSensorRecorder.accelerometerData(from:to:)`. This class confirms to `NSFastEnumeration` protocol. So I tried the trick mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25872991/5603109. However since I am using Xcode Version 8.0 beta (8S128d), it no longer works.

What can I do to make it support `for-in` loops?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Swift 3, `SequenceType` has been renamed to `Sequence` (the "Type" suffix has been removed from protocols), `generate()` has been renamed to `makeIterator()` (the concept of a "Generator" has been replaced by an "Iterator") and therefore `NSFastGenerator` has also been renamed to `NSFastEnumerationIterator`.

Thus you'll want your extension to look like this:

```
extension CMSensorDataList : Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}
```