# Iterator protocol vs. Generator vs Iterator in swift

Tags: swift, iterator, generator

After doing some research, I have not been able to find any concrete confirmation, but it seems as though the Generator associated type of the sequence protocol has been renamed to iterator. Is this correct?

I cant find anything on the swift API reference about the protocol GeneratorType or the associated type Generator. I'm only seeing people write about it on blogs.

So my question is do generators and iterators refer to the exact same concept in swift?

Comment: In a word; yes.

Comment: Somewhat related: [NSFastEnumeration in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37829953/2976878). Also see [the evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md) for the Swift 3 renamification of the standard library.

Comment: Thanks Hamish both those links were useful. Had a feeling that was the case, just couldn't find concrete confirmation. Thanks for peace of mind. If you just post that information in the form of an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do generators and iterators refer to the exact same concept in Swift?

In a word; yes.

As said in [the evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md) for the Swift 3 'renamification' of the standard library:

> - Strip `Type` suffix from protocol names. In a few special cases this means adding a `Protocol` suffix to get out of the way of type names that are primary [...].
> - The concept of generator is renamed to iterator across all APIs.

As a consequence, the [`GeneratorType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/GeneratorType/) protocol has been renamed to [`IteratorProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/iteratorprotocol).

The [`SequenceType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/) protocol was renamed to [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence), and went from looking like this:

```
public protocol SequenceType {

  associatedtype Generator : GeneratorType

  // ...
  func generate() -> Generator
  // ...
}
```

to looking like this:

```
public protocol Sequence {

  associatedtype Iterator : IteratorProtocol

  // ...
  func makeIterator() -> Iterator
  // ...
}
```